# How to run the ant-design website locally

Tags: reactjs, npm, antd

I'm trying to run the project locally. I'm following the instructions which are straightforward. But when running npm start I get this huge error as seen below.

I'm following this very simple guidelines: https://ant.design/docs/react/contributing#Development-Workflow

```
➜  ant-design git:(master) npm start

> antd@4.17.0-alpha.3 prestart
> npm run version


> antd@4.17.0-alpha.3 version
> node ./scripts/generate-version


> antd@4.17.0-alpha.3 start
> antd-tools run clean && cross-env NODE_ENV=development concurrently "npm run color-less" "bisheng start -c ./site/bisheng.config.js"

antd-tools run clean
[0] 
[0] > antd@4.17.0-alpha.3 color-less
[0] > node ./scripts/generate-color-less
[0] 
[0]  less render start!
[1] ℹ Compiling   Bisheng
[1] ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost/
[1] ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from undefined
[1] ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/_site
[1] ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /index.html
[1] /home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/webpack/lib/Dependency.js:311
[1]             throw new Error(
[1]             ^
[1] 
[1] Error: module property was removed from Dependency (use compilation.moduleGraph.updateModule(dependency, module) instead)
[1]     at ProvidedDependency.set (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/webpack/lib/Dependency.js:311:9)
[1]     at iterationDependencies (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/bisheng/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:940:21)
[1]     at /home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/bisheng/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:950:8
[1]     at /home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/bisheng/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:409:6
[1]     at /home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/bisheng/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:155:13
[1]     at eval (eval at create (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/bisheng/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:14:1)
[1]     at /home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin/index.js:178:9
[1]     at /home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin/index.js:125:7
[1]     at /home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin/index.js:125:7
[1]     at CaseSensitivePathsPlugin.fileExistsWithCase (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin/index.js:95:5)
[1]     at /home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin/index.js:118:10
[1]     at CaseSensitivePathsPlugin.getFilenamesInDir (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin/index.js:52:5)
[1]     at CaseSensitivePathsPlugin.fileExistsWithCase (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin/index.js:101:8)
[1]     at /home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin/index.js:118:10
[1]     at Array.<anonymous> (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin/index.js:72:5)
[1]     at Storage.finished (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
[1] events.js:291
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1] 
[1] Error: write EPIPE
[1]     at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:831:20)
[1]     at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:702:19)
[1]     at process.<anonymous> (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/bisheng/lib/loaders/common/worker.js:15:11)
[1]     at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
[1]     at emit (internal/child_process.js:902:12)
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
[1] Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
[1]     at internal/child_process.js:835:39
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
[1]   errno: -32,
[1]   code: 'EPIPE',
[1]   syscall: 'write'
[1] }
[1] events.js:291
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1] 
[1] Error: write EPIPE
[1]     at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:831:20)
[1]     at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:702:19)
[1]     at process.<anonymous> (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/bisheng/lib/loaders/common/worker.js:15:11)
[1]     at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
[1]     at emit (internal/child_process.js:902:12)
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
[1] Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
[1]     at internal/child_process.js:835:39
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
[1]   errno: -32,
[1]   code: 'EPIPE',
[1]   syscall: 'write'
[1] }
[1] events.js:291
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1] 
[1] Error: write EPIPE
[1]     at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:831:20)
[1]     at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:702:19)
[1]     at process.<anonymous> (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/bisheng/lib/loaders/common/worker.js:15:11)
[1]     at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
[1]     at emit (internal/child_process.js:902:12)
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
[1] Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
[1]     at internal/child_process.js:835:39
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
[1]   errno: -32,
[1]   code: 'EPIPE',
[1]   syscall: 'write'
[1] }
[1] events.js:291
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1] 
[1] Error: write EPIPE
[1]     at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:831:20)
[1]     at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:702:19)
[1]     at process.<anonymous> (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/bisheng/lib/loaders/common/worker.js:15:11)
[1]     at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
[1]     at emit (internal/child_process.js:902:12)
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
[1] Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
[1]     at internal/child_process.js:835:39
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
[1]   errno: -32,
[1]   code: 'EPIPE',
[1]   syscall: 'write'
[1] }
[1] events.js:291
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1] 
[1] Error: write EPIPE
[1]     at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:831:20)
[1]     at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:702:19)
[1]     at process.<anonymous> (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/bisheng/lib/loaders/common/worker.js:15:11)
[1]     at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
[1]     at emit (internal/child_process.js:902:12)
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
[1] Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
[1]     at internal/child_process.js:835:39
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
[1]   errno: -32,
[1]   code: 'EPIPE',
[1]   syscall: 'write'
[1] }
[1] events.js:291
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1] 
[1] Error: write EPIPE
[1]     at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:831:20)
[1]     at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:702:19)
[1]     at process.<anonymous> (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/bisheng/lib/loaders/common/worker.js:15:11)
[1]     at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
[1]     at emit (internal/child_process.js:902:12)
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
[1] Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
[1]     at internal/child_process.js:835:39
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
[1]   errno: -32,
[1]   code: 'EPIPE',
[1]   syscall: 'write'
[1] }
[1] events.js:291
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1] 
[1] Error: write EPIPE
[1]     at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:831:20)
[1]     at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:702:19)
[1]     at process.<anonymous> (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/bisheng/lib/loaders/common/worker.js:15:11)
[1]     at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
[1]     at emit (internal/child_process.js:902:12)
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
[1] Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
[1]     at internal/child_process.js:835:39
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
[1]   errno: -32,
[1]   code: 'EPIPE',
[1]   syscall: 'write'
[1] }
[1] events.js:291
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1] 
[1] Error: write EPIPE
[1]     at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:831:20)
[1]     at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:702:19)
[1]     at process.<anonymous> (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/bisheng/lib/loaders/common/worker.js:15:11)
[1]     at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
[1]     at emit (internal/child_process.js:902:12)
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
[1] Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
[1]     at internal/child_process.js:835:39
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
[1]   errno: -32,
[1]   code: 'EPIPE',
[1]   syscall: 'write'
[1] }
[1] events.js:291
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1] 
[1] Error: write EPIPE
[1]     at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:831:20)
[1]     at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:702:19)
[1]     at process.<anonymous> (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/bisheng/lib/loaders/common/worker.js:15:11)
[1]     at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
[1]     at emit (internal/child_process.js:902:12)
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
[1] Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
[1]     at internal/child_process.js:835:39
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
[1]   errno: -32,
[1]   code: 'EPIPE',
[1]   syscall: 'write'
[1] }
[1] events.js:291
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1] 
[1] Error: write EPIPE
[1]     at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:831:20)
[1]     at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:702:19)
[1]     at process.<anonymous> (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/bisheng/lib/loaders/common/worker.js:15:11)
[1]     at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
[1]     at emit (internal/child_process.js:902:12)
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
[1] Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
[1]     at internal/child_process.js:835:39
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
[1]   errno: -32,
[1]   code: 'EPIPE',
[1]   syscall: 'write'
[1] }
[1] events.js:291
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1] 
[1] Error: write EPIPE
[1]     at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:831:20)
[1]     at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:702:19)
[1]     at process.<anonymous> (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/bisheng/lib/loaders/common/worker.js:15:11)
[1]     at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
[1]     at emit (internal/child_process.js:902:12)
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
[1] Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
[1]     at internal/child_process.js:835:39
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
[1]   errno: -32,
[1]   code: 'EPIPE',
[1]   syscall: 'write'
[1] }
[1] events.js:291
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1] 
[1] Error: write EPIPE
[1]     at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:831:20)
[1]     at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:702:19)
[1]     at process.<anonymous> (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/bisheng/lib/loaders/common/worker.js:15:11)
[1]     at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
[1]     at emit (internal/child_process.js:902:12)
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
[1] Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
[1]     at internal/child_process.js:835:39
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
[1]   errno: -32,
[1]   code: 'EPIPE',
[1]   syscall: 'write'
[1] }
[1] events.js:291
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1] 
[1] Error: write EPIPE
[1]     at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:831:20)
[1]     at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:702:19)
[1]     at process.<anonymous> (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/bisheng/lib/loaders/common/worker.js:15:11)
[1]     at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
[1]     at emit (internal/child_process.js:902:12)
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
[1] Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
[1]     at internal/child_process.js:835:39
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
[1]   errno: -32,
[1]   code: 'EPIPE',
[1]   syscall: 'write'
[1] }
[1] events.js:291
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1] 
[1] Error: write EPIPE
[1]     at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:831:20)
[1]     at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:702:19)
[1]     at process.<anonymous> (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/bisheng/lib/loaders/common/worker.js:15:11)
[1]     at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
[1]     at emit (internal/child_process.js:902:12)
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
[1] Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
[1]     at internal/child_process.js:835:39
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
[1]   errno: -32,
[1]   code: 'EPIPE',
[1]   syscall: 'write'
[1] }
[1] events.js:291
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1] 
[1] Error: write EPIPE
[1]     at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:831:20)
[1]     at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:702:19)
[1]     at process.<anonymous> (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/bisheng/lib/loaders/common/worker.js:15:11)
[1]     at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
[1]     at emit (internal/child_process.js:902:12)
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
[1] Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
[1]     at internal/child_process.js:835:39
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
[1]   errno: -32,
[1]   code: 'EPIPE',
[1]   syscall: 'write'
[1] }
[1] events.js:291
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1] 
[1] Error: write EPIPE
[1]     at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:831:20)
[1]     at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:702:19)
[1]     at process.<anonymous> (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/bisheng/lib/loaders/common/worker.js:15:11)
[1]     at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
[1]     at emit (internal/child_process.js:902:12)
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
[1] Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
[1]     at internal/child_process.js:835:39
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
[1]   errno: -32,
[1]   code: 'EPIPE',
[1]   syscall: 'write'
[1] }
[1] events.js:291
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1] 
[1] Error: write EPIPE
[1]     at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:831:20)
[1]     at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:702:19)
[1]     at process.<anonymous> (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/bisheng/lib/loaders/common/worker.js:15:11)

-- MARK: StackOverflow doesnt allow more than 30.000 characters, so I have removed some lines here.

[1] Error: write EPIPE
[1]     at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:831:20)
[1]     at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:702:19)
[1]     at process.<anonymous> (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/bisheng/lib/loaders/common/worker.js:15:11)
[1]     at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
[1]     at emit (internal/child_process.js:902:12)
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
[1] Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
[1]     at internal/child_process.js:835:39
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
[1]   errno: -32,
[1]   code: 'EPIPE',
[1]   syscall: 'write'
[1] }
[1] events.js:291
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1] 
[1] Error: write EPIPE
[1]     at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:831:20)
[1]     at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:702:19)
[1]     at process.<anonymous> (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/bisheng/lib/loaders/common/worker.js:15:11)
[1]     at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
[1]     at emit (internal/child_process.js:902:12)
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
[1] Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
[1]     at internal/child_process.js:835:39
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
[1]   errno: -32,
[1]   code: 'EPIPE',
[1]   syscall: 'write'
[1] }
[1] events.js:291
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1] 
[1] Error: write EPIPE
[1]     at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:831:20)
[1]     at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:702:19)
[1]     at process.<anonymous> (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/bisheng/lib/loaders/common/worker.js:15:11)
[1]     at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
[1]     at emit (internal/child_process.js:902:12)
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
[1] Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
[1]     at internal/child_process.js:835:39
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
[1]   errno: -32,
[1]   code: 'EPIPE',
[1]   syscall: 'write'
[1] }
[1] events.js:291
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1] 
[1] Error: write EPIPE
[1]     at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:831:20)
[1]     at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:702:19)
[1]     at process.<anonymous> (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/bisheng/lib/loaders/common/worker.js:15:11)
[1]     at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
[1]     at emit (internal/child_process.js:902:12)
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
[1] Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
[1]     at internal/child_process.js:835:39
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
[1]   errno: -32,
[1]   code: 'EPIPE',
[1]   syscall: 'write'
[1] }
[1] events.js:291
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1] 
[1] Error: write EPIPE
[1]     at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:831:20)
[1]     at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:702:19)
[1]     at process.<anonymous> (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/bisheng/lib/loaders/common/worker.js:15:11)
[1]     at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
[1]     at emit (internal/child_process.js:902:12)
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
[1] Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
[1]     at internal/child_process.js:835:39
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
[1]   errno: -32,
[1]   code: 'EPIPE',
[1]   syscall: 'write'
[1] }
[1] events.js:291
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1] 
[1] Error: write EPIPE
[1]     at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:831:20)
[1]     at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:702:19)
[1]     at process.<anonymous> (/home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/node_modules/bisheng/lib/loaders/common/worker.js:15:11)
[1]     at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
[1]     at emit (internal/child_process.js:902:12)
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
[1] Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
[1]     at internal/child_process.js:835:39
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
[1]   errno: -32,
[1]   code: 'EPIPE',
[1]   syscall: 'write'
[1] }
[1] bisheng start -c ./site/bisheng.config.js exited with code 1
[0]  Theme generated successfully. OutputFile: /home/jeggy/Coding/IdeaProjects/ant-design/_site/color.less
[0]  less render end!
[0] npm run color-less exited with code 0
➜  ant-design git:(master)
```

Comment: I also get a lot of errors when trying to run antd locally, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution in this thread: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/33444

It is a problem with Webpack. Run

```
npm i -D webpack@^4.44.0
```

then

```
npm start
```

should work